# SwitchCurrent Config "Error reading registry values"

Tags: .net, registry

I'm trying to use an application that the rest of my team is successfully using.

I've added the registry keys and they are exactly where they should be.

The code that's failing is a simple authentication with tables in a SQL database and the registry keys hold the username/password/server ip.

The code is failing at

```
SwitchCurrent.Config.GetProvider(String dsn)
```

Exception Message:

```
"Error reading registry values for connection string in PGandE - ..Config"
```

Stack Trace:

```
   at SwitchCurrent.Config.GetProvider(String dsn)
   at ...Linq.Shared.SharedDataContext..ctor(String dsn) in C:\Users\Mike Gaughan\Code\...\...\...\Shared\SharedDataContext.cs:line 68
   at ..Rest.Security.AuthProvider.Validate(TokenRequest tokenRequest, Employee& employee) in C:\Users\Mike Gaughan\Code\...\...\Security\AuthProvider.cs:line 26
```

I have made sure all permissions on the keys are granted to User.

I am running my Windows dev environment on VM Fusion through a Mac OS, but I do not see that being the issue as everything else runs fine.

I know I'm poorly portraying the issue, but I really am not being given much information and not sure if anyone has any stabs in the dark I can try.

Answer (score 0):

Obvious solution.

The registry key I was given was missing some required values.